# google mapUnable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

hi im new in android i want add google map to my project but i have exception

logcat:

```
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747): Process: net.learn2develop.LBS, PID: 3747
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.LBS/net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-06 08:07:06.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3747):     ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (map == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
        // present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

mainfest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.learn2develop.LBS"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
 
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
 
    <permission
        android:name="net.learn2develop.LBS.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 
    <uses-permission 
      android:name="net.learn2develop.LBS.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name=
            "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name=
            "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity 
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAN15Q7PhiOzuE5NaEdU_77XfacZihi-co" />
 
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

`MapView` causing issue because currently you are trying to cast `MapView` to `SupportMapFragment` which is not valid.

In code get `MapView` instead of `SupportMapFragment` as:

```
MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
if(mapView!=null){
   map = mapView.getMap();
}
```

**OR**

Second way is,use `fragment` with `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in xml:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(4087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.LBS/net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're looking for a Fragment:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

But in your layout, `map` is a view:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

Either replace it with `findViewById`:

```
map = findFragmentById(R.id.map).getMap();
```

or use a `MapFragment` instead of a `MapView` inside your layout:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

(Also, when getting a view or fragment, it's always best practice to check if they're null before calling a method on them).

Comment: `MapView` extends `FrameLayout` so it's a `View` instead of `Fragment`. so i think need to use `findViewById` instead of `findFragmentById` which is used for `Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction`

Comment: 09-06 09:15:01.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.LBS/net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-06 09:15:01.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-06 09:15:01.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

Comment: Make sure you've imported `Fragment` in your activity: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: 09-06 13:19:08.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 13:19:08.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2232): Process: net.learn2develop.LBS, PID: 2232
09-06 13:19:08.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2232): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.LBS/net.learn2develop.LBS.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment